# Debug dart program

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a Flutter app and I run it through a VS Code launch.json configuration.  I have a dart executable that I wish to run in the same project directory with the VS Code debugger attached.

The problem is, whenever I start any dart configuration, it tries to open my dart program with my selected device instead of just the console.  I wish to run my dart program with the VS Code debugger attached without a device selected, just in the console.

Comment: show your launch.json for a [mre].